# Raster conditional tool unexpected results. What's wrong?

Tags: arcpy, raster, raster-calculator, conditional

I have a DEM raster (High: 53441, Low: -3444, unit: cms) with negative values, and I want to make all values 100 or less to be 100.

[image]

I've tried Raster Calculator, and also python. I've got the same unexpected result: (High: 22881, Low: 8842)

[image]

This is my code in python:

```
inRaster  = Raster('ns_dem_int')
outRaster = Con(inRaster, 100, inRaster, "Value <= 100")
outRaster.save("DEM14")
```

I've run the code -and the Raster Calculator- several time (with some variations) but I've always end up with those numbers as results
Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont squeeze your brains anymore!

Finally, I realized that everything I did was correct.
The problem was with ArcGIS. The display of the resulting raster in the Table of Contents was wrong. For some reason that I don't know, it was showing the wrong Max and min values.
Lesson learned: when in doubt, always double check your outputs/results by more than one way.
This issue is resolved.
Thanks to all who read this question, and learn from this too (it costed me a long & frustrating day of work!)
If this helped you solving your problem, please share that.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to [`Con`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) can be a conditional raster instead of an input raster.

Try `outRaster = Con(inRaster <= 100, 100, inRaster)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That I've tried before, didn't work. Any other idea?

Comment: I dont' know if this is relevant: Values in raster are numeric-long type.

Comment: Rephrase: That I've tried before, exactly the same unexpected results.